# How to keep duplicate Mongo database in sync with main one?

Tags: mongodb, flask, architecture, pymongo

I have a Flask app connected to a MongoDb using PyMongo. I am looking for guidelines on how to accomplish the following:

1. Keep two identical mongo databases in sync.
2. If main database is down
   have Flask app connect to second one in order to perform requested
   operations.
3. If one database goes down, have both re-sync once both
   again up and running.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB implements this out of the box with replica sets.